# Como criar um botão caso esteja logado em uma conta

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, login

Olá, Gostaria de saber quando alguém esta logado para criar um botão do tipo FILE.
Esta criado o sistema de cadastro e login, porem não sei como saber quando ele esta logado ou não.

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>LuppBox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo_index.css"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#0099FF">
 <ul id="cabecario">
     <li id="logo"><img src="fotos_site/logo.png" width="auto" height="60" /></li>  
        <li id="login_cadastro_css"><a href="login_cadastro.php">Login | Cadastro</a></li>         
    </ul>  
</body>
</html>
```

fazer_login.php

```html
<?
 include "connection.php";
 
 $login = $_POST['login_entrar'];
 $senha = $_POST['senha_entrar'];
 
 $sql = mysqli_query($coneccao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'"); 
 
 
 while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
 {
  $senha_db = $linha['senha'];
 }
 
 $cont = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
 
 if($cont == 0)
 {  
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
  <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Este usuario não existe')</script>";  
 }
 else
 {
  if($senha_db != $senha)
  {
   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
   <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Senha incorreta')</script>"; 
  }
  else
  {
   session_start();
   
   $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $login; 
   $_SESSION['senha_usuario'] = $senha;
   
   header("location: perfil.php"); 
  }
 }
 
 mysqli_close($coneccao);
?>
```

fazer_cadastro.php

```html
<?
 include "connection.php";
 
 $login = $_POST['login_entrar'];
 $senha = $_POST['senha_entrar'];
 
 $sql = mysqli_query($coneccao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'"); 
 
 
 while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
 {
  $senha_db = $linha['senha'];
 }
 
 $cont = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
 
 if($cont == 0)
 {  
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
  <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Este usuario não existe')</script>";  
 }
 else
 {
  if($senha_db != $senha)
  {
   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
   <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Senha incorreta')</script>"; 
  }
  else
  {
   session_start();
   
   $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $login; 
   $_SESSION['senha_usuario'] = $senha;
   
   header("location: perfil.php"); 
  }
 }
 
 mysqli_close($coneccao);
?>
```

Gostaria de colocar um botão do tipo FILE ali em baixo daquele  caso você esteja logado.

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como faço: Eu divido página em pequenos blocos HTML e vou montando mediante condições, condições estas que podem ser o logon do usuário desta forma:

```
session_start();
if((!isset($_SESSION['email']) == true) and (!isset($_SESSION['pass']) == true)){
        unset($_SESSION['email']); 
        unset($_SESSION['pass']);
        require_once 'components/modals/login-modal.php';
        require_once 'components/modals/create-account-modal.php';
    }else{
        require_once 'components/modals/logout-modal.php';
    }
```

dentro de cada arquivo com extensão .php tem um HTML puro que pode ou não ser acoplado a página. utilizo a super global $_SESSION para armazenar os valores de logado.

Comment: .@LucasCarezia por favor de um upvote em minha resposta já que ela lhe foi útil.

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se a sessão está ativa usando o método [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php).

```
    if ( isset($_SESSION["login_usuario"]) && isset($_SESSION["senha_usuario"])) {
        echo "<button type=\"button\">Botão</button>";
    } else {
        echo "Usuário não entrou.";
    }
```

Uma dica: você pode definir a sessão como um `array`, fica mais fácil de se utilizar, veja:

```
$login = "john_doe";
$senha = password_hash("soeuseiasenha", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$_SESSION["usuario"] = array();
$_SESSION["usuario"] = $login;
$_SESSION["senha"]   = $senha;
```

Então pra manipulá-la basta fazer isso:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION["usuario"]) ) {
    echo "...";
}
```

Comment: Olá Eduardo, mas ele não consegue verificar, ele sempre diz que não estou logado mesmo eu estando.

Comment: Você quer colocar esse botão em qual página, @LucasCarezia? Lembre-se de colocar o `session_start()` na primeira linha de seu script php.

Comment: Colocar na index.php